# Difficulty getting Rails up and Running

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I'm trying to get rails up and running, but I can't seem to get bast the up part.

Fist I run

```
rails new test_app
```

Inside the application I run

```
bundle install
```

but when this happens I get a slew of errors - at the start it says "ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension. (Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError)"

EDIT:

Gist of issue https://gist.github.com/747423.

OS: OSX 10.6.5
RUBY: 1.8.7
RAILS: 3.0.1
XCODE: 3.2.2

can someone give me an idea of how to get this set up right,

Thanks

Comment: What operating system are you using? Could you paste the error in a gist at gist.github.com and paste a link here?

Comment: At least give us operating system.

Comment: Hi, just added that stuff, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps you don't have a compiler installed? Like the commenters have said we need to know your platform and also we need to see more of the error message context.

**EDIT**

That's better. Your problem appears to be an incomplete or too-old installation of sqlite3. I'd suggest following the instructions in the error message and installing sqlite3 via macports (or fink or homebrew depending on preference).

You may also like to install RVM for a more flexible way to maintain ruby installations. It has gemsets which can really help to avoid polluting your system-wide rubygem collections with hundreds of old gems.

Comment: I've run sudo port install sqlite3 +universal but that doesn't seem to help the problem.  Originally I gave you the answer, because I did that and it worked fine in that project, but I set up a new project and did this and I'm getting the same error.